# flip animation is not working in chrome on mac OS X

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a dashboard in that I am using CSS3 flip animations,the flip animations are working fine in windows but when comes to chrome on Mac OS X the flip animation is flickering when I am hovering on that DIV.Please provide me some fix.

Thanks.

### CSS:

Here the problem is only with 'back face' when I am hovering on that div it is flickering.

```
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#f1_container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -ms-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.no-flick{
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a Codepen, fiddle or Stack Overflow snippet?

Comment: Having same issue. Would love an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue using Chrome 57 on OSX. Upon flipping the card, the back would show briefly and then disappear to white.

My solution was to set `background-color: white;` on the front and back instead of the flip container. Not 100% sure why the background color is an issue but it flips correctly now with no flicker! :)

Comment: Thanks for providing your fabulous solution. The issue was solved so many months back. Even though I would appreciate your response with exact solution what I did before.